# Chess GUI with Time Handicap for Engine vs Engine matches

Tags: analysis

I want Stockfish to play for 1 hour per move and I want Komodo to play for 2 minutes per move. Is there a GUI that can do this?

Arena has the option to set the seconds per move but both engines will have the same time control. I want a different time control for each engine.

Comment: i find this question interesting but the result is inevitable they are running on the same machine, the time control is huge in favor of stockfish, and  furthermore, stockfish is already the best engine out there, and you give it a huge time advantage, inevitable for sure

Comment: Not anymore. Komodo has gone over Stockfish.

Comment: I am using this in creating an Opening book.

If Komodo win TCEC 7 then I will buy Komodo 9 and give it 1 hour playing time and SF for 2 minutes. I am just looking for a GUI that can do this. Thanks

Comment: Stockfish 8 was the champion in TCEC 2016, also first in CCRL at the time  of this writing (just to illustate the point they very close to each other and constantly exchanging 1st/2nd/3rd, Houdini 5 is currently 2nd).

Answer (score 2):

Arena can do this!

Suppose a game has a time control with x minutes for y move(s). In your case you need x=2 for Komodo and x=60 for Stockfish. You achieve this by doing the following:

Go to menu **Engines > Manage** and in the tab **Details** find each engine in the left panel **Installed Engines**. In the right panel **Selected Engine** go to the tab **Special** and change the value for **Strength(%)**. In your case, when starting a game with 60 minutes for 1 move, the adjusted strengths would be:

- Stockfish 100%; resulting in 1*60 minutes for 1 move
- Komodo ~3%; resulting in 0.03*60 minutes for 1 move